# onResume not always call after exit with home button

Tags: java, android

I was wondering what may be the reason for this strange behavior.
From time to time (rarely) in my app when I exit it with the home button and then get back onResume is not called and for some strange reason the data I loaded in onCreate is gone. I have ListView with items and in the case when onResume is not called, the list is empty and no items are displayed and no matter how many times I exit with the home button and get back it stays empty, unless I press back or kill the app.

What may be the reason behind that. I read some articles that this might be caused by endless loop. But I have no idea how to test it and how to find the reason for this.

I will be glad to have some advice if someone has encountred that behavior or knows what the possible issue might be

Comment: [Android Life-cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). If Apps with higher priority need memory it's possible the Activity will close - this can be an even bigger problem with devices that have very little memory. This is during the `onPause` phase.

Comment: so this might be a device problem? Is there a way to test that or see if this is the case? Also I should note that app doesn't go through onDestroy in this case.

Comment: By loading a ton of apps, while your activity is in the background? You should save the data during the `onPause` phase to local storage - as there is no guarantee the user will resume the app. Any info you insert in the list won't be re-loaded automatically unless you specifically had it loaded during the `onCreate`, or `onResume`.

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to be the problem. Closed all background apps but still could get onResume to work.
Also how can I assign the saved data to the ListView since no event is called when I return back?